# Is there any way to define a customized code block in Intellij Idea 13 and collapse/expand it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-13

I have a large text code and want to collapse/expand some part of the code that I want. Intellij Idea 13 can do it on some predefined block with CTRL+SHIFT+ NUMPad -/+ , But I want to define my own block and collapse/expand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options to fold a custom block.

**IntelliJ Idea 14:**
Select multiple lines and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd>.

**Previous IntelliJ Idea versions:**
Surround multiple lines with `{...}` (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Then you can use the fold/expand icons.

**Folding by comment:**

Visual Studio style:

```
#region Description 
your code
#endregion
```

NetBeans style:

```
// <editor-fold desc="Description"> 
your code
// </editor-fold>
```